# How to connect to guest VM(KVM) on a remote Server

Tags: linux-kvm

I am running a few VMs using KVM in a remote server. I want to access these VMs from my laptop.

Setup:
VM-A and VM-B are hosted in Host-Z.

Host-Z can be accessed through a public IP, We don't have options to add more than one public IP.

I want to access VM-A by Host-Z-Public IP:2222 VM-B by Host-Z-public IP:3333 from my local laptop. Is this possible ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you ask your KVM VPS host? SolusVM? OpenVZ? They will know. You want to secure shell to the respective host using port 2222 or port 3333?

Comment: I am seting up VMs in a remote lab, Yes I want secure shell to the respective host using port 2222 or port 3333 from my laptop.